# Getting permission Error while calling API method using valid oauth2 access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, permission-denied, erpnext

I am trying to authenticate using bearer token.

When I am trying to call the api with valid `oauth2.0` access token

```
https://**************/api/method/frappe.auth.get_logged_user
```

I am getting this error response.

```
{
    "exc": "[\"Traceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \\\"/home/frappe/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/app.py\\\", line 66, in application\\n    response = frappe.api.handle()\\n  File \\\"/home/frappe/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/api.py\\\", line 56, in handle\\n    return frappe.handler.handle()\\n  File \\\"/home/frappe/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/handler.py\\\", line 21, in handle\\n    data = execute_cmd(cmd)\\n  File \\\"/home/frappe/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/handler.py\\\", line 54, in execute_cmd\\n    is_whitelisted(method)\\n  File \\\"/home/frappe/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/handler.py\\\", line 64, in is_whitelisted\\n    raise frappe.PermissionError('Not Allowed, {0}'.format(method))\\nPermissionError: Not Allowed, <function get_logged_user at 0x7f9c027a9c08>\\n\"]",
    "_server_messages": "[\"{\\\"message\\\": \\\"Not permitted\\\"}\"]"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without the code base. But it looks like the

```
execute_cmd(..)
```

is raising a Permissions error. I think the problem is with the script itself running on that machine. i.e. Not necessarily the access token. But without code this is a guess. You could verify by manually running that script when logged into the machine with the same user/permissions as when running as a web server.